# Dependency injection issue in rails 7 & ruby 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry-rb

I have a simple rails app using `dry-container` & `dry-auto_inject` by dry-rb to inject a service on controller, this method working well on rails 6 & below and ruby 2.7 & below .

A service I created under `app/services/v1`

```
module V1
    class PostService
        ...
    end
end
```

I registered a class of service under `lib/marka/`

```
require 'dry-container'
require 'dry-auto_inject'

module Marka
    class DiContainer
        extend Dry::Container::Mixin
        
        register :v1_post_service do
            V1::PostService.new
        end
    end
    INJECT = Dry::AutoInject(Marka::DiContainer)
end
```

And try to include on controller under `app/controllers/api/v1/`

```
require 'marka/di_container'
module Api
  module V1
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
      include Marka::INJECT[:v1_post_service]

      def search
         render json: { status: "OK" }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm getting an error looks like

```
Started POST "/api/v1/posts/search.json" for ::1 at 2022-02-16 00:26:43 +0000
  
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):
  
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:150:in `initialize'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:108:in `initialize'
dry-auto_inject (0.9.0) lib/dry/auto_inject/strategies/kwargs.rb:71:in `block (2 levels) in define_initialize_with_splat'
dry-auto_inject (0.9.0) lib/dry/auto_inject/strategies/kwargs.rb:22:in `new'
dry-auto_inject (0.9.0) lib/dry/auto_inject/strategies/kwargs.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in define_new'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:251:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:850:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.0.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:99:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:26:in `call'
railties (7.0.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (7.0.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.0.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (7.0.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
activesupport (7.0.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
railties (7.0.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:93:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (7.0.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:137:in `call'
railties (7.0.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'
puma (5.6.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:252:in `call'
puma (5.6.2) lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'
puma (5.6.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (5.6.2) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'
puma (5.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:441:in `process_client'
puma (5.6.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: `dry`s documentation is always a bit confusing because it seems to say things and then display different implementations like "...then the arguments will be a single splat, e.g. `#initialize(**args)`." Looks like a double splat to me? Either way it looks like the confusion might be that `UrlFor` uses argument forwarding `(...)` and `Metal` takes no arguments for initialize. I think this confuses the auto injector into passing args when it shouldn't? Maybe open this issue with dry instead?

Comment: @engineersmnky I'm not sure `UrlFor` uses argument fowarding into `Metal` since there is no changes on there, I mean `Metal` always takeing no arguments.

Comment: @engineersmnky seems like there are many changes here https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8a3fcad2d2a0400af495988562c1c5eac8217a06

Answer (score 1):

This is because `initialize` changed in Rails. In general, it's not a good idea to use dry-auto-inject in 3rd-party code, because it may break like in this case. I moved the related issue to dry-rails repo as we may want to create a compatibility extension for Rails, see here https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-rails/issues/53.